# Django - jquery : populate combobox based on selection of another combobox

Tags: django, jquery, django-forms

I am quite new to Django and jquery stuff. I am trying to populate a comboBox (ChoiceField in Django) based ont the choice selected in another comboBox (without reloading the page).

I can't find any simple example of such a basic application of ajax.

For now I'm call the following ajax function when I select an item from the first dropdown list.

```
function get_asset_from_type(){
        var type_asset = $("#id_type").val();
        var data = {type_asset:type_asset};
        var args = {type:"POST", url:"/asset/etatType/", data:data};
        $.ajax(args);

        alert(type_asset);

        return false;
};
```

It alerts the right type but gives a 403 error on the given url. Weird thing is this url works the first time I load the page. I don't understand what's going on..

EDIT:
403 error seems to be gone, remains the initial question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're running up against a CSRF problem. As Django by default blocks POST requests that do not have a CSRF Token with a 403. There are a couple ways to deal with this in JS. One is to pull the value out of the cookie, the code to do that can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

or you can do it by passing the CSRF_TOKEN in with the javascript script tag:

```
<script src='myjavascript.js?CSRF_TOKEN={{ csrf_token }}'></script>
```

Note that it's using a double braket, instead of {%%}. This gets the value of the token, instead of the form input.

```
function getOptionsFromScriptSrc() {
    // Get last script tag in parsed DOM.
    // Due to the way html pages are parsed, 
    // the last one is always the one being loaded.

    var options = {}
    var js_src = $('script').last().attr('src');

    if(js_src.match(/\?/)) {
        var options_list = js_src.split('?')[1].split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < options_list.length; i++) {
            var tmp = options_list[i].split('=');
            options[$.trim(tmp[0])] = $.trim(tmp[1]);
        }
    }

    return options;
}

function get_asset_from_type(){
    var options = getOptionsFromScriptSrc();
    var type_asset = $("#id_type").val();
    var data = {type_asset: type_asset, csrfmiddlewaretoken: options['CSRF_TOKEN']};
    var args = {type:"POST", url:"/asset/etatType/", data:data};
    $.ajax(args);

    alert(type_asset);

    return false;
};
```

I haven't, of course, tested this code, but I have used this method before and it works pretty well.

---

To the main problem of populating a select box, you need to specify a callback for your ajax post, and then deal with the data returned from your server:

```
function get_asset_from_type(){
    var options = getOptionsFromScriptSrc();
    var type_asset = $("#id_type").val();
    var post_data = {type_asset: type_asset, csrfmiddlewaretoken: options['CSRF_TOKEN']};

    $.post('/asset/etatType/', post_data, function(data){
        // Assuming server is going to respond with the html of the options, eg: <option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option>...
        $('#id_ofmyselectbox').append(data);
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Don't seem to have an error anymore. Thanks! Now I still have the population of the dropdown list issue. No clue of where to start ..

Comment: Ahh. I just noticed that your .ajax call doesn't have a callback. A callback is needed whenever you have an ajax request, because the request is asynchronous. The callback is there to run when the server responds. A couple things: 1. I would use $.post (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of $.ajax, it's just a little cleaner. 2. What is your server going to respond with? JSON, XML, HTML?

Comment: My server is going to respond with HTML, for now at least

Comment: Ok, is it going to respond with just the html that should go in the select box? IE, no <html><head>...</body></html>, just <option value='1'>One</option>, etc?

Comment: I guess so, I'm not so sure about how I should handle it actually. But this seems enough to get started

Comment: I've updated my post with the way I would handle it, assuming the data is going to be formatted as html options. Again, untested code, but should work in theory.

Comment: @ChrisPickett let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2757/discussion-between-johanna-and-chris-pickett)